# Is there a single word for "But anyway"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I would love to know if we have a single word that can be used in general speaking and writing in place of "But anyway".

Comment: Some example sentences would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Yet* is a somewhat rare alternative to *but*, yet it is well suited to the usage in question:

> **yet** – adverb 3 – Nevertheless; in spite of that:
>   
>   *‘every week she gets worse, and* yet *it could go on for years’*
>   
>   [– OxfordDictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/yet#yet__8)

*And* may be omitted before *yet*, as in the first sentence of this answer, leaving an equally acceptable variation of the dictionary example:

> *‘every week she gets worse,* yet *it could go on for years’*

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the context, but my first impression is that you are signaling the end of a digression.

Some suggestions:

- Anyway
- anyhow
- regardless
- nevertheless

Comment: Good answer, but +1 especially for ‘nevertheless’.

Comment: I am not interested at the moment for the offered position. However I am willing to discuss *nonetheless* to see if the position interest the folks in my network.

Comment: Are you trying to ask if that usage of _nonetheless_ correct? @MaNKuR

Comment: @Max Yes, kind of. I just tried to put an example here for my reference and hopefully it will help others as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

However would substitute for "but anyway". For example, the wind was howling and the rain pelting down, however, we made it home without mishap. It has the same meaning but is shorter.

Comment: Note, however, that when introducing a clause with *however* formal use requires that the preceding clause be closed with a point more disjunctive than a comma: a full stop, semicolon or em dash.